# How do I setup and start a unix socket in Red Hat?

Tags: linux, debian, rhel, socket

I couldn't find any specific guides for creating a unix socket in Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL version 9.3) so I used this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-asgi-django-app-with-postgres-nginx-and-uvicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04#step-5-creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn).

After creating the **gunicorn.socket** and **gunicorn.service** file in  **/etc/systemd/system/**, I ran

```
sudo systemctl start gunicorn.socket
```

but got an error.

```
Failed to start gunicorn.socket: Unit gunicorn.socket not found.
```

I tried this procedure on Debian, creating the file and starting the socket successfully.
Here is what I tried so far on RHEL:

1. changed the ownership of the **gunicorn.socket** file to root with read and write privileges.
2. moved the gunicorn.socket file to **/etc/systemd/user** directory and ran the same command with no luck.
3. rebooted system
4. tried starting the units after running **sudo systemctl daemon-reload** while files were in **/etc/systemd/system** directory (See screenshot)
5. tried creating another **test.socket** file and starting the unit with a different failure (See 2nd screenshot near the end)

[image: screenshot]

Here is my **gunicorn.socket** file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

and my **gunicorn.service** file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/product-catalog
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/product-catalog/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          app:app


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image: 2nd Screenshot]

and the **test.socket** file:

```
[Unit]
Description=test socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/test.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: (1) It might help if you showed us your `gunicorn.socket` file.  (2) Did you create a `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` file?  Show us that, too, please.  (3) Did you reboot?          Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You should move the files back to `/etc/systemd/system`, and then run `systemctl daemon-reload` so that systemd is aware of the change, and then try starting the units

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this problem: your service and socket units work fine for me (when installed in `/etc/systemd/system`).

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but after I recreated the gunicorn.socket and gunicorn.service files, I no longer see errors and verified that the socket unit started successfully.